# Инвалидация ключей в react-query v5

Tags: reactjs

```
export const useMutation = <T, D>(config: MutationType) => {
  const {path, method, token, queryKeyRefetch} = config
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const {
    mutateAsync: mutate, isPending: loading, data, error, status,
  } = useReactQuery({
    mutationFn: (args: T) => fetcher<T>({path, method, args, token}),
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log(error)
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({queryKey: queryKeyRefetch});
    },
  });
  return {
    mutate, loading, data: data as D, error, status
  };
};
  const {mutate: registerInTournament, loading} = useMutation<TournamentTeamCreate, TournamentTeamCreate>({
    path: `/games/${gamePk}/tournaments/${tournamentPk}/teams`,
    method: 'POST',
    token: true,
    queryKeyRefetch: [`/games/${gamePk}/tournaments/${tournamentPk}/teams/?team__users=${user?.id}`, `/games/${gamePk}/tournaments/${tournamentPk}/`]

  })
```

Почему при инвалидации ключей, когда я передаю 1 ключ, то все ок, если в массиве два ключа, то инвалидация вообще не происходит?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше приводить в виде текста.

Comment: Извиняюсь, поправил